# Use Ledger Wallet as etherbase for mining on private network

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, ledger-nano-s

I would like to use my ledger as the wallet that will validate blocks on a private network with a `geth` client.

I can have access to my ledger account from `geth`. But i can't start the mining process.

```js
> miner.start()
...
null
> WARN [04-03|10:21:02.553] Block sealing failed     err="not supported"
...
```

I look for what caused this error in the source code and i think [it's here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/2fa9e99fc19d2804d2409ab5904f4c154e70e6cd/accounts/usbwallet/wallet.go#L497)

Is it technically possible but not implemented yet / never will be or is it totally impossible to use a wallet that come from an other backend to validate blocks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that validator needs to sign validated blocks with his private key, which looks reasonable.  In theory, it is possible to use hardware wallet for this.  The wallet just need to either support signing arbitrary data (probably some wallets [already support this](https://ledgerhq.github.io/btchip-doc/bitcoin-technical.html#_developer_mode)), or to support signing validated private network blocks.

The comment in `geth` source you mentioned code just means that `geth` currently does not know how to sign validated block.

Once private networks with dedicated validators will become more popular, hardware wallets will most probably gain ability for signing validated blocks, and `geth` will learn how to use it.